# worpdress enqueue jquery ui core in header

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I have searched this on google but couldn't find a satisfaying answer. I'm trying to load jquery ui core in my header in worpdess, but can't seem to find the way to do so. In my function.php file I'm doing this :

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

This loads the script but in the footer. Anyone knows if it's possible? Or should I deregister jquery ui and use a CDN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts');
    function my_theme_scripts(){
        if( is_admin() ) return;
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.1' );
    }
```